# Why isnt "new" throwing error if class is not declared in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

Lets have two files: index.php and foo.php
The foo.php file would be placed in **subdirectory /lib**

now in index.php, lets have this function

```
function bar(){
  require('foo.php');
  $foo = new Foo();
  $foo->bar();
}
```

And in foo.php

```
class Foo{
  public function __construct(){
      echo "baz";
  }

  public function bar(){
     echo "bar";
  }

}
```

Now, the error is hard to spot: I made error in requiring the class Foo, because instead `require('lib/foo.php')` I wrote only `require('foo.php')`

That error is really hard to spot, especially if you have many lines of code.

Now **should declaration of class throw an error?**

If I would get error on the line `$foo = new Foo();` the error would be easy to spot. In this case you get `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Foo::bar()` which makes you think: "But I declared the **method**" and you forget that the error ight be somewhere else.

So, **why does not PHP throw any error on creating new class which does not exist?**

Comment: It does. https://3v4l.org/2as94. Which means that there is a class `Foo` on the same namespace that's already defined, only without the `bar()` method.

Comment: Perhaps you declared the `lib` directory in the `include_path`?

Comment: comment the require out and see if it still works.. if it does you know for sure PHP is finding it elsewhere.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha yes, there actually was same class in the namespace. Once in main directory and once in /lib subdirectory. I did not discover it until now. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP ***does*** throw a fatal error when you are trying to instantiate a class which is not currently loaded and is not autoloadable either. The most likely explanation for your situation is that you *do* have a class `Foo` declared and included somewhere, but it's not the class `Foo` you expect.

In fact, the `require` call should have died first before `new` was even reached. You *do* have another `class Foo` in `foo.php`.